# Access User Interface without access to database

Tags: ms-access, user-interface, vba, ms-access-2010

Just a brief question.
I have an access database with a login screen, graphs for classified data etc. 
However, it is not restricted in any way. It should not be possible to enter tables and forms.

What should I look for here?

I.e. the user should not have access to the source code and data. Only the user interface with whatever i put on it.

Best regards, Emil.

Comment: Compile to mde or accde.

Comment: I tried the accde but i dont see how to restrict. Do you have any sources i can read from?

Answer (score 1):

If you use the 2007/2010 access database files (accdb) you have only limited options. The older Access versions (mdb files) allow detailed security settings. 
Some things you can also do in Access 2010 are:

- Use a database password (File, Encrypt with Password)
- Save the database in ACCDE format. Then users can’t view or change your form design or code anymore, but they can still access the tables. (File, Save & Publish, Make ACCDE, Save As)

Comment: Hi Edgar. Thank you for the answer. Is the database password applied in access? And is there a method to make these detailed security options - Perhabs by buying some third party software?